# Linux screen command scrollback one screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

In the `screen` command manual, it states that after entering copy/scrollback mode, `ctrl+b` is supposed to scrollback one screen(like Page Up in vim). But, in my machine, first `ctrl+b` will scroll one line. It is only the second and more `ctrl+b` will be scrolling one screen. This behavior also happens for page down as well. First `ctrl+f` will only scroll one line, second and more `ctrl+f` will be scrolling one screen. Is this an issue or intended?

Comment: Our condolences? Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working as intended. The cursor starts out at the bottom of the current page; pressing <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> moves it up to the top of the page, plus one line (just as if you'd pressed <kbd>↑</kbd> 25 times, or however many rows are on your screen).

Comment: So `ctrl+b` is really moving the cursor number of lines of my screen, not really the same as PageUp. I thought it would act like PageUp, because vim and less PageUp is really one full screen scroll, no matter where your cursor is. So, the doc is misleading, the doc says: "C-b and C-f scroll the display up/down a full screen", which is not always true.

Comment: The behavior of Ctrl+B is identical to PageUp in screen's copy mode. It's not necessarily the same as page up in all other applications; not all programs work the same way.

Comment: Yes, I understand they may not work the same. But, I meant the doc they published makes it sound like ctrl+b should act like PageUp. This is copy pasted from their doc: "C-b and C-f scroll the display up/down a full screen".